# Make JSON from SQL query output

Tags: text-formatting, json, sql

I have this database query:

```sql
select hostname,size from tableinfo
```

The output is like this:

```
  hostname                   size
------------------------- -----------
  host1                        28
  host2                        13
  host3                        79
  host4                        28
  host5                        17
```

Or, I can make it like this:

```
host1                        28
host2                        13
host3                        79
host4                        28
host5                        17
```

I want to write a shell script that converts this output to JSON, but I don't really know where to begin or what to do.
The JSON must be like this:

```json
{
   "data":[
   {  "{#HOSTNAME}":"host1",  "{#SIZE}":"28"  } ,
   {  "{#HOSTNAME}":"host2",  "{#SIZE}":"13"  } ,
   {  "{#HOSTNAME}":"host3",  "{#SIZE}":"79"  } ,
   {  "{#HOSTNAME}":"host4",  "{#SIZE}":"28"  } ,
   {  "{#HOSTNAME}":"host5",  "{#SIZE}":"17"  }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using a database engine that is able to produce JSON output?

Comment: @Kusalananda not with this format. it only produce it in a way that only db can use

Comment: The required keys are strange `"{#HOSTNAME}" ... {#SIZE}`. Any options to have a more readable keys?

Comment: @BlackCrystal PostgreSQL, for example, is a database engine that can both read and write JSON.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest application need it like that

Comment: @Kusalananda i should use this output in another application

Comment: @BlackCrystal So if your database engine was able to produce JSON, you would just have to change your query a bit and would not have to insert an additional processing step.  Also, it would be easier to get the plain output from JSON than JSON from the plain output, if your database engine supports JSON output.

Comment: @Kusalananda i can use something like `select '{ "{#HOSTNAME}":"'||hostname)||'", "{#SIZE}":"'||size|| '"  }'  from tableinfo` but i can't execute this in bash. bash mistake | and " and '

Comment: @BlackCrystal What database engine are you actually using?

Comment: @Kusalananda DB2

Comment: You may want to look at getting the output of the query directly as JSON: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/sqlp/rbafyjsonpublishing.htm

Comment: thats db2 for i not db2 for LUW

Comment: @BlackCrystal Once you know that a function called 'json_object' exists, a simple search should turn the documentation for your DB2 variant. [Here are docs for the JSON_OBJECT function on DB2 11.1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0070412.html#r0070412).

Comment: mine is not 11.1.its lower

Comment: @Kusalananda  thank you for your answers and time. i finally found the answer and wrote my script after hours :)

Comment: @Haxiel thank you for your time and answers i finally found the answer and wrote my script :)

Comment: @BlackCrystal Good to know :-). Do consider adding your solution as answer here, so that it may help a future reader.

Answer (score 4):

[**`jq`**](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) solution:

```
 <your sql output> | jq -Rs '{"data": [split("\n") | map(select(length > 0))[] 
                             | split(" +";"g") 
                             | {"{#HOSTNAME}": .[0], "{#SIZE}": .[1]}]}'
```

The output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host1",
      "{#SIZE}": "28"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host2",
      "{#SIZE}": "13"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host3",
      "{#SIZE}": "79"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host4",
      "{#SIZE}": "28"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host5",
      "{#SIZE}": "17"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks it will work but i'm not allowed to install extra package on any system.

Comment: @BlackCrystal ask your systems administrators to install it for you

Comment: @roaima I am the administrator. we are not allowed to install any packages before a lot of test. once a package was not compatible with another important packages (not the version)  and we ran into disaster.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an SQLite3 database (other database engines will have their own native ways to produce JSON output):

```bash
sqlite3 database.db \
    '.mode json' \
    'SELECT hostname AS `{#HOSTNAME}`, size AS `{#SIZE}` FROM tableinfo' |
jq '{ data: . }'
```

This gets the data in JSON format from the database as an array, and then uses `jq` to insert it under a `data` key in an object.  The SELECT query changes the names of the keys used for the hostnames and sizes according to what is required.

This gives you a JSON document that is equivalent to what you ask for:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host1",
      "{#SIZE}": "28"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host2",
      "{#SIZE}": "13"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host3",
      "{#SIZE}": "79"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host4",
      "{#SIZE}": "28"
    },
    {
      "{#HOSTNAME}": "host5",
      "{#SIZE}": "17"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you want the *exact* format of the output that you mention, then replace the `jq` command in the pipeline above with the following [`jtc` command](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc):

```bash
jtc -T '{"data": {{}} }' -tc
```

This would insert the data read from `sqlite3` into a template, as the value of the `data` key, and the `-tc` would cause `jtc` to produce its "half-compact" pretty-printed output format, and it would look like this:

```json
{
   "data": [
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host1", "{#SIZE}": "28" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host2", "{#SIZE}": "13" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host3", "{#SIZE}": "79" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host4", "{#SIZE}": "28" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host5", "{#SIZE}": "17" }
   ]
}
```

---

From your tabular data (the two simple columns), you can use [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create the initial array and then the same `jq` or `jtc` command to insert it all under the `data` key:

```bash
$ mlr --n2j -S label '{#HOSTNAME},{#SIZE}' file | jtc -T '{ "data": {{}} }' -tc
{
   "data": [
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host1", "{#SIZE}": "28" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host2", "{#SIZE}": "13" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host3", "{#SIZE}": "79" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host4", "{#SIZE}": "28" },
      { "{#HOSTNAME}": "host5", "{#SIZE}": "17" }
   ]
}
```

I use `--n2j` as a shorthand for `--inidx` and `--ojson` ("read toolbox indexed formatted data, write JSON"), and I added `-S` to stop Miller from inferring that the size data should be integers (and instead tread it as strings).

Comment: Beware [jq, mlr (don't know about jtc) expect UTF-8 encoded JSON which sqlite3 doesn't necessarily produce](/q/757832)